# Performance : Insert or Update index selection

Tags: java, performance, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I have a table with 9 columns. The combination of 5 (let's call them `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `F`) of these columns compose a unique identification (primary key) of each row. Let's call the remaining 4 `G`, `H`, `I`, `J`

I'm trying to insert or update 150.000 rows with a `WHERE` clause containing these 5 columns. What I'm doing right now is this

```
SELECT 1 FROM table_name WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE A = STRING_HERE
AND   B = STRING_HERE
AND   C = STRING_HERE
AND   D = NUMBER_HERE
AND   F = NUMBER_HERE
```

If the result has an entry I do an update like this

```
UPDATE table_name
SET G=NUMBER_HERE,
    H=NUMBER_HERE,
    I=NUMBER_HERE,
    J=NUMBER_HERE
WHERE A = STRING_HERE
AND   B = STRING_HERE
AND   C = STRING_HERE
AND   D = NUMBER_HERE
AND   F = NUMBER_HERE
```

If it doesn't I just execute an `INSERT` statement.

Right now the `SELECT` statements are not in the overall transaction.
The `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements are in a transaction (`autocommit` set to `false`).

Right now I'm using a `CLUSTERED` index on the combination of `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `F`. Maybe a `NON-CLUSTERED` would be better?

The majority of the calls will be `UPDATE` statements (something like 70% or more) 
The overall task is taking too long to complete (about an hour).

Do you have any ideas, dos and don'ts, in order to improve the performance of the task mentioned?

I've begun to try executing the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements as batches, but even the `SELECT` statements take too long. Moreover, in order to avoid any runtime disasters, should I execute the batch for every X entries?

I'm using Java and JDBC with prepared statements for executing the commands and SQL Server 2008. No ORM is used.

No race conditions to be considered. This is an `isolated` task. No data will be changed during this operation from another source/action.

Comment: Are you doing insert/Update one record at a time or what?

Comment: It's a transaction, so commit will be called once at the end. But yes, every operation is single. Right now I'm converting the logic to use batches. Will something like this improve significantly the overall performance? If yes, then should I keep in mind any pitfalls?

Comment: Yes of course it you will see huge difference in performance and i suggest one more thing
for insert and update just use join/where clause, i mean you don't check for each record that if record exists then update else insert. Let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please provide an example for `just use join/where clause`? Moreover is the `CLUSTERED` index appropriate or should a `NON-CLUSTERED` index provide better performance for the aforementioned scenario?

Comment: Obviously clustured will be better, can you tell me how you are going to do for batch update/insert?

Comment: I have two arraylists. One for the inserts one for the updates. Depending on the result of the select statement I add to one of the lists the values needed to generate the prepared statement. When generating the statement I add it to a batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below steps if it suits for you.

1. Insert all records in temp table using bulk insert
2. Create one stored procedure
3. For Insert :
      insert into table_name(A,B,...) select A,B,.... from #table_temp i
                where not exists(select A From table_name i1 where i.A = i1.A and i.B = i1.B, ....(All PKs))
4. For Update :
      update table_name set G=i.G, ...
      from #table_temp i where exists(select A From table_name i1 where i.A = i1.A and i.B = i1.B, ....(All PKs))
5. Call this SP.

Let me know if you need anymore help